# Extra space above the image in Microsoft Outlook 2007

Tags: php

We've created an HTML template that is rendering correctly on all email clients except for one issue with Outlook 2007. In outlook we get an extra space above the image when that content is placed in the last position. But the problem is solved when I change its position from last position. Can anyone please help me out to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please provide some more information like your code.

Comment: I think the source of your html template + css may help...

Comment: PHP? If this is really being done using PHP, post the code. If not, retag your question.

Comment: @Michiel, @i_freyre, @sims : Below is the link for the HTML file of my newsletter- http://beta.messagesherpa.com/app/webroot/NL/Dockscape_Marine/Copy_of_February_Newsletter1936.html

Comment: Is their is any possibility that the problem is in the image itself, because their is no problem with the other images.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML document contains numerous external stylesheets with tricks too complex for Outlook 2007 to understand.

Microsoft replaced the IE-based rendering engine in previous Outlook versions with the Word-based HTML rendering engine in 2007 and 2010.

You will need to alter your HTML to be more primitive and use far less CSS.  [Here's a document describing some of the problems in the Word rendering engine](http://www.email-standards.org/clients/microsoft-outlook-2007).  There are a few tools, including the well-regarded [Litmus](http://litmus.com/email-previews) service, that will show you how HTML emails look in various clients, so you can compose adequate HTML.

Comment: Even I tried by removing the external CSS, but that has no effect on the image spacing issue.

Answer (score 0):

Put img.imgclass {vertical-align: bottom; display: block} and this should help.